# Database connection to XAMPP from C#

Tags: c#, database

I'm using XAMPP as my SQL database server.

I'm trying to connect to it but it's not working.

```
namespace InventoryManagement
{
      public partial class Form1 : Form
      {
            public string dbconnect = "Server=127.0.0.1;User=root@localhost;password=;database=inventory;";

      }

      private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection();
           connect.ConnectionString = dbconnect;
           connect.Open();

           if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
           {
                 MessageBox.Show("connected");
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: Is there any exception thrown when connect.Open() is called?

Comment: Your connection string seems invalid. It should be like this: `Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=yourpassword;Database=inventory;`.

Comment: i tried but its still not working

Comment: What do you mean by `not working` ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try this

```
public string conn = "server=localhost; user id = root; database=inventory";
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: While your code may correct as answer But Elaborating what your code does, It can improve the quality of your answer. Checkout the Article : [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)